# Using a Tiagra/105 front derailleur with R3000 shifters

Tags: shimano, derailleur, shifter, compatibility, derailleur-front

The Sora 2x derailleur mech that came with my gravel bike broke in half. Is the 2x Tiagra/105 front derailleur compatible with the R3000 shifters? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Shimano specs and compatibility info [here](https://si.shimano.com/#/) (expand *Technical Documents* on left hand side).

The [front drivetrain compatibility chart](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com/?cid=C-453&acid=C-455) says the ST-R3000 lever is only compatible with the FD-R3000 front derailleur.

If you study the compatibility chart you'll see there tends to be a lot of compatibility between drivetrains that match in number of speeds, but not between speeds. For instance 2x10 Ultegra 6700, 105 5700 and Tiagra <strike>4700</strike>/4600 are all compatible with each other but not 2x9 or 2x8 group components.

Update:

I recalled a [question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/60360/24228) where the asker had a Trek bike with a Sora drivetrain and 105 front derailleur. Obviously Trek thinks this works and Shimano are known to be conservative in their specifications and compatibility recommendations.

Comment: But if you already own the FD in question you could always give it a try.

Comment: 4700 Tiagra isn't compatible with any older 10 speed groupsets as they changed it to be like the 5800/6800/9000 11 speed groupsets. Officially, it's only compatible with 4700, but the FD works with Shimano 11 speed shifters.

Comment: Any Shimano road shifter 10 speed and below (except Tiagra 4700) works properly on any Shimano derailleurs designated 9 speed and below.  This includes designated mountain mechs. Obviously a 10s road shift will work with a 10s road derailleur, but things get too different here as mountain 10 speed systems (DynaSys) significantly changed the length of cable pull/derailleur movement.  Also, some older duraAce series can only be used together. Spacing of the cassette sprockets differ as the number of them increase, so that's involved too but derailleurs don't know or care what "speed" they are

Comment: @jeff That's true for *rear* derailleurs, because it's known that Shimano used a 1:1.7 actuation ratio for MTB 9 and below and road 10 and below. *Front* derailleurs are a different matter. I've never seen any comprehensive information on their actuation ratios and cable pulls.

Comment: @Argenti Apparatus  I've found in practice that the front shifting systems are less finicky than rear.  For instance, my Giant mtb front end, combined a Deore 9 speed shifter--a left 3 speed actually, SL-590, controlling a Shimano 7 speed/triple front mech (model number in the 100's) perfectly.  Now I have no probs after changing to a Deore FD-M611, which is marketed as 10 speed. My Stumpjumper got a new 10 speed triple crankset (FC-622) which meshes perfect with the stock 9 speed system. I did assume the same relationship exists up front  that is documented for the rear, but maybe not.

Comment: I consider the linked question to be poor evidence of cross-compatibility. The question was asked because the setup _wasn’t_ working. I do not believe the setup was specified by Trek, as the replacement bike was full Sora which solved the problems. I’d rollback the answer update is what I’m getting at

Comment: @Swifty I think the 105 derailleur was in fact Trek's specification, and the issue was caused by the installation of a 10 speed chain rather than a 9.

Comment: Issue was not isolated to the chain alone, cos the chain and mech were swapped out together. It also does not state if the mech was fd-3500 or fd-r3000, which is an important distinction given they are not compatible with each other by your own linked specifications. Please show me one spec sheet where 105 gets mixed into sora drive trains by Trek. Can’t find one in the trek [archive for Zektor](https://archive.trekbikes.com/uk/en/2017/Trek/zektor_two_dk#/uk/en/2017/Trek/zektor_two_dk/details) or [here](https://archive.trekbikes.com/uk/en/2017/Trek/zektor_3#/uk/en/2017/Trek/zektor_3/details)

Comment: Anyway, suggestions for improvement: paragraphs 1 and 2 are a good start, but I don't think the answer has a meaningful conclusion, yes or no, its a little implicit and should be strengthened. It's also not clear/self-contained if you're referencing front or rear derailleurs in para 3. Then para 4 comes along and seems to contradict para 3. (I've explained why I think para 4 has zero evidential value).